# Play Store - Error about distrubuted selected countries

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to publish a closed test on Play Console, however, I get this error "Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_ILLEGAL_TO_DISTRIBUTE_IN_SELECTED_COUNTRIES". Even if I select one country, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug.

The error message should normally tell you that you are not allowed to publish in this country based on your content rating.